# How will i get Api key and API secret for enable Authenticate Using Twitter in google cloud firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I am working on Google Firebase and I want to give login with twitter in my project but when I enable login with twitter then two mandatory fill pop up. one is this the API key and second one is the API secret. I tried to find API key and API secret for fill these mandatory but I did not get key and secret. Where will I get this API key and API secret?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#before_you_begin) has a step-by-step guide on setting up Twitter authentication in your Firebase project. To get those API keys, you would have to register you app as developer application using [Twitter Developer Portal](https://developer.twitter.com/apps). You can find those keys in Twitter Developers dashboard:

[image]

> Make sure your Firebase `OAuth redirect URI` (e.g. `my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`) is set as your Authorization callback URL in your app's settings page on your Twitter app's config.